# Sort by string with two columns

Tags: sql-order-by

I have a table 'relationships' like below

```
id | user_1_nick | user_2_nick

 1   peter         kevin
 2   jake          peter
 3   peter         abby
 4   aaron         abby
 5   abby          kevin
```

So if Peter is logged in his 'friends' will be shown as below

```
1    abby
2    jake
3    kevin
```

And Abbys 'friends' as below

```
1    aaron
2    kevin
3    peter
```

I hope you get me.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM relationships AS r 
LEFT JOIN members AS m 
ON (r.user_2 = m.hash AND r.user_2 != '$userhash') 
OR (r.user_1 = m.hash AND r.user_1 != '$userhash') 
WHERE (user_2 = '$userhash' OR user_1 = '$userhash') 
AND accepted = '1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In MySQL**

You have to filter the friends in both directions and merge the results as illustrated below.

So the friends of `peter` could be fetched with the query:

```
SELECT A.FRIENDS FROM 
(SELECT user_2_nick friends FROM relationships
WHERE user_1_nick='peter'
UNION
SELECT user_1_nick friends FROM relationships
WHERE user_2_nick='peter') A
ORDER BY A.FRIENDS;
```

And for `abby` with:

```
SELECT A.FRIENDS FROM 
(SELECT user_2_nick friends FROM relationships
WHERE user_1_nick='abby'
UNION
SELECT user_1_nick friends FROM relationships
WHERE user_2_nick='abby') A
ORDER BY A.FRIENDS;
```

Here is the **[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bd58d/3)**

Comment: First of all thank you! I updated my question and hope you can help me with the query.

Comment: My answer yields your expected result. See the DEMO.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks for helping out!